# Python 文字起こしプログラムがうまく起動しない

Tags: python

PythonでJupiterLabを使いました。初心者です。

音声ファイルを選択し、そのファイルを１分毎分割して、文字起こしをし、そのデータをExcelに書き出すというプログラムを作成しました。

結果、音声ファイルの最初の１０秒程度を数回、文字起こしして、Excelに書き出さないです。

どのように改善したらいいでしょうか、アドバイスお願いします

コード

```
import wave
import struct
from scipy import fromstring,int16
import numpy as np
import os
import math
import speech_recognition as sr
import pandas as pd
import tkinter.filedialog

def cut_wav(filename,time):  

    wavf = filename
    wr = wave.open(wavf, 'r')

    ch = wr.getnchannels()
    width = wr.getsampwidth()
    fr = wr.getframerate()
    fn = wr.getnframes()
    total_time = 1.0 * fn / fr 
    integer = math.floor(total_time*100) # 小数点以下切り捨て
    t = int(time*100)  # 秒数[sec]
    frames = int(ch * fr * t /100)
    num_cut = int(integer//t)
    data = wr.readframes(wr.getnframes())
    wr.close()
    X = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=int16)

    for i in range(num_cut + 1):
        
        outf = out_dir + '/' + str(i) + '.wav' 
        
        
        if i > 0:
            start_cut = int(i*frames) - int(100000)
        else:
            start_cut = int(i*frames)
            
            
        end_cut = int(i*frames + frames)
        Y = X[start_cut:end_cut]
        outd = struct.pack("h" * len(Y), *Y)
        
        ww = wave.open(outf, 'w')
        ww.setnchannels(ch)
        ww.setsampwidth(width)
        ww.setframerate(fr)
        ww.writeframes(outd)
        ww.close()
        
    str_cut = ""
    list1 = [wavf,"",""]
    df_x = pd.DataFrame([list1])
    df_x.columns = ['NO','音声ファイル','変換結果']
    
    for ii in range(num_cut + 1):
        cutf = out_dir + '/' + str(ii) + '.wav'
        str_out = wav_to_text(outf)
        df_x.loc[ii] = [ii,str(ii) + '.wav',str_out]
        
    with pd.ExcelWriter(out_file) as writer:
        df_x.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='結果',index=False)
        
def wav_to_text(wavfile):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    with sr.AudioFile(wavfile) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
        
    wav_to_text = r.recognize_google(audio,language='ja-JP')
        
    print(wav_to_text)
    
    return wav_to_text

out_dir= "output"
file = os.path.exists(out_dir)

if file == False:
    os.mkdir(out_dir)
    
fTyp = [("", ".wav")]
iDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(_))
f_name = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fTyp, initialdir=iDir)

cut_time = 60
out_file = "output/out.xlsx"
cut_wav(f_name,float(cut_time))
```

Comment: 所々printを入れて状況を表示確認しているようですが、どの段階まで正常に動作していて、どの段階でどう異常になっているか、追記してみてください。判らないなら、もう少し細かいステップでprintを入れるとか、文字起こし処理を行わずに作成済みダミーデータを用意してExcelに書き込めるか試すとかしてみてください。

Comment: 検索するとこの辺の記事が色々と出てきますが、何か参考になれば。[Python × AIで議事録作成プログラムを作ってみる(伊沢剛)](https://tkrel.com/12983), [動画音声から自動的に文字を起こしてＣＳＶ化してみた【動画編集らくらくシリーズ②】](https://morymory.com/2021/03/19/%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%93%EF%BD%96%E5%8C%96%E3%81%97/), [pythonで長い音声・動画からの文字起こしを実装する](https://www.hamlet-engineer.com/posts/mojiokoshi_long.html)